# Select columns in place (in for loop)

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a list of DataFrames that all have columns ['a', 'b', 'c']:

```
list_ = [df1, df2, df3]
```

and want to run the following loop:

```
for lst in list_:
    lst['x'] = 'abc'
    lst = lst[['a', 'x']]
```

When I print list_[0], I see the new column 'x' but also all the other columns. Why was the first line in the loop executed but the second not?

Answer (score 2):

The first line operates in-place on the original reference to the data. However, the second line reassigns the variable `lst` with a slice from the original data, but this assignment doesn't modify the original data frame, as only the (temporary) name `lst` is now pointing to different data.

One solutions:

```
def fix(lst):
    lst['x'] = 'abc'
    lst = lst[['a', 'x']]
    return lst

list_ = [fix(lst) for lst in list_]
```

Or a solution without list comprehension based on in-place dropping columns:

```
s = ['a', 'x']
for lst in list_:
    lst['x'] = 'abc'
    lst.drop([c for c in lst.columns if c not in s], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! But I was also wondering if there wasn't a built-in pandas function to do that. It seems weird that I would have to define new functions to operate on multiple dataframes.

Comment: Oops yes, let me check

Comment: Updated, yet another solution ;-)